# Why call WaitOne if you're just calling End right after? Doesn't End block?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Trying to understand [this MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228962.aspx) but I'm confused about these lines:

```
IAsyncResult result = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(args[0], null, null);
Console.WriteLine("Processing request for information...");
// Wait until the operation completes.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
// The operation completed. Process the results.
try 
{
    // Get the results.
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(result);
```

For example, why even use asynchronous programming if you're just going to block the thread until the task completes anyway? Also, what good does calling `WaitOne` do? Doesn't the End function automatically block until the operation completes?

Pretty confused over here..

Comment: That's not what it looks like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143989%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `EndGetHostEntry` blocks until the operation has completed. I suspect it's just a bad example, to be honest - possibly it's *trying* to show you two different ways of waiting until the operation has completed, but by putting them in the same example it's just added to confusion.

Likewise it would certainly have been more useful if it had included a comment of "// do more work here" or something like that.

It sounds like your understanding of the API is fine, and you should probably just ignore the example - or add a note at the bottom in the "user content" section to mention all this.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet! Heh, I wish my understanding was fine. Been asking questions on here all night trying to get all this stuff down :p